# How to distribute data and computation to maximize locality?

Tags: hadoop, parallel-processing, distributed, bigdata, nosql

Please bear with me, this is a basic architectural question for my first attempt at a "big data" project, but I believe your answers will be of general interest to anyone who is starting out in this field.

I've googled and read the high-level descriptions of Kafka, Storm, Memcached, MongoDB, etc., but now that I'm ready to dig in to start designing my app, I still need some further insight on how in fact the data should be distributed and shared.

The performance of my app is critical, so one objective is to somehow maximize the locality of the data in the RAM of the machines doing the distributed calculations.  I need advice for this part of the design.

If my app had some clear criteria for a priori sharding the data and distributing the calculations (such as geographical regions or company divisions) then the solution would be obvious.  But unfortunately my app's data access patterns are dynamic and depend on the results of previous calculations.

My app is an analysis program with distinct stages.  In the first stage, all the data is accessed once and a metric is calculated for each data object.  In the second stage, a subset of the data objects may be accessed, with the probability of access being proportional to each data object's metric that was calculated in the previous stage.  In the final stage, a relatively small subset of data objects will be accessed many times for many calculations.

At all stages, it is required that the calculations be distributed across several servers.  The calculations are embarassingly parallel, and each distributed calculation only needs to access a few data objects.  It is also required that the number of servers can be specified before the app runs (for example, run on one server, or run on fifty servers).

It seems to me that I need some mechanism that distributes the appropriate data objects to the appropriate compute servers, as opposed to just blindly fetching the data from some database service (whether centralized or distributed).  Also, it seems to me that some sort of smart caching system might be appropriate, since the data access pattern depends on the previous calculations and cannot be predicted a priori.  But as far as I can tell, Memcached is not such a system because the sharding is determined a priori.

I've read many times that the operating system cache performs better than any monkeying around that we may try.  I think the ideal solution is that each compute server's RAM cache somehow captures the data objects' dynamic access patterns, but it's not clear to me how this would work with a NoSQL or Memcached service.

Thanks for bearing with me this far.  I realize this is a basic question, but the answer eludes me so far.  I can't resolve the dynamic access patterns of my app with the a priori sharding of the NoSQL/Memcached packages.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For clarification, I want to avoid work similar in spirit to this:  <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16879815/optimizing-network-bandwidth-over-distributed-database-aggregation-jobs>

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to take a look at http://tarantool.org. Shard to maximize locality for the most common data access pattern, use Lua for local computations, and net.box to issue a remote RPC when calculation needs to continue on another node. All data is stored in RAM, if you write your computation code carefully it could take advantage of the Just In Time compiler.

Comment: But I don't think these particular tools address my main problem: a priori sharding of the database cannot match the dynamic distribution of the computation.  There is no "most common data access pattern".  I need something that either moves the data to the computation, or the computation to the data (and preferably manages load balancing).

Comment: Tarantool is an application server + database engine, combined. You're free to ship your computation (Lua), to whichever node you need. If you're thinking about a distributed database which dynamically adjusts its data layout based on the access pattern, I remember NuoDB had a plan to do it a couple of years ago - I don't know where they are now with this plan. Clarifying what sort of computation you have in mind would make it easier to give an advice on the most suitable instrument.